# How to bind class with List of Objects as property to repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

We have class which we use in ascx-page, in repeater:

Class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id;
    ...

    public int NumPeople { get; set };

    public List<ReservationOccupancy> ReservationOccupancyList { get; set };
}
```

Header:

```
<th id="tdNumPeople" runat="server">
    asp:Image ID="Image15" runat="server" CssClass="sortico" ImageUrl="/img/blank.gif" />
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandName="NumPeople" Text="# of Guests "></asp:LinkButton></th>
      <th id="tdSource" runat="server">
      <asp:Image ID="Image16" runat="server" CssClass="sortico" ImageUrl="/img/blank.gif" />
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CommandName="Source" Text="Source "></asp:LinkButton></th>

        <% for (int i = 0; i < SOcolu.Length; i++)
        {
        %><th><%= SOcolu[i] %></th>
        <%   } %>
```

ItemTemplate:

```
<td><%#Eval("NumPeople") %></td>
   <td>
     <asp:Label ID="lblSource" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  <td><%#(List<ReservationOccupancy>)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ReservationOccupancyList") %> 
    </td>
```

We use Eval for it's properties, but also in class we have List of Object:

```
public List<ReservationOccupancy> ReservationOccupancyList
```

ReservationOccupancy class:

```
public class ReservationOccupancy
{
        public string ColumnName;

        public int ColumnValue;
}
```

We want to show repeater like this - for example, we have List of:

```
ReservationOccupancyList = new List<ReservationOccupancy>()
{
    { ColumnName = "ColumnName1", ColumnValue = 1 },
    { ColumnName = "ColumnName2", ColumnValue = 2 }
},
```

```
Id   NumPeople   ColumnName1   ColumnName2
-------------------------------------------
5       3             1            2
```

We can show/bind NumPeople, but when we are trying to bind List (for example, with datacontainer) we get reference to a generic collection as a value in view.

Comment: You haven't shown the markup for your Repeater in your question. That's important to include.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing it as 
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ReservationOccupancyList[0].ColumnValue")
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ReservationOccupancyList[1].ColumnValue")
etc.

On this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder.eval?view=netframework-4.8 I found this explanation:

"The navigation path from the container object to the public property value to be placed in the bound control property. This must be a string of property or field names separated by periods, such as Tables[0].DefaultView.[0].Price "

Which sounds to me like you have to give DataBinder.Eval the path through the list to a specific field, because it can't just render a list.

Hopefully this helps, or at least gets you pointed in the right direction.